# rxpy how to unsubscribe

Tags: python, reactive-programming, reactivex

```
from rx import Observable, Observer
from rx.subjects import Subject
drive = Observable.from_list(list(range(33))).publish()

s = Subject()
xs = s.buffer_with_count(6).do_action(print)
xs.subscribe(print)

ss = Subject()
xss = ss.buffer_with_count(6).do_action(print)
xss.subscribe()

drive.subscribe(s)
drive.subscribe(ss)

drive.connect()
```

This is my code.
I only find the way to subscribe,but if i want remove s or ss from drive.
**what can i do.**
The question is how to unsubscribe s and ss.

Answer (score 3):

`drive.subscribe(s)` is returning a *Disposable*. Calling `dispose()` on that is unsubscribing your observer.

```
d1=drive.subscribe(s)
...
d1.dispose()
```

Comment: For subjects/multicast, you can just call .dispose on the Subject itself (if I remember correctly)